# Tilling in oak stump grinding chips for new sod lawn

Tags: lawn

I have a fair amount of live oak chips/dirt from a stump I just ground. Is it a good idea to till these grind 'spoils' into the dirt of an area we plan on laying new sod into? Will the decomposition of the oak deplete the soil to the point that the sod struggles? Is the oak too acidic for sod? Should I incorporate top soil or another amendment as well? Thank You

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't till in the oak chips - they're best composted first and then reused on the garden.  They will deplete nitrogen as they break down; wood chips take a good while to decompose, so they'll be robbing nitrogen ongoing while they do, which won't be a great start for your lawn. You also need a loose friable surface to lay the sods on to facilitate good rooting into the soil beneath - if you till in oak chips, they're not something that could be described as friable.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a nice uniform lawn, the important part is that the soil composition is uniform. In other words don't till in the chips just at he site of the stump - spread it out a bit. Albeit, some nitrogen is required for decomposition of cellulose, but it shouldn't be an issue; add a bit of high nitrogen fertilizer as every suburbanite does, if needed.